# pdf document error on download

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, download

Hello I have some pdf files in my website which the users can download but the problem is when  we download these pdf file and try to open the pdf I get an error " There was an error in opening the document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired" but on the contarary this works fine in my local system.
Please guide me , Here is my code

```
function download_pdf($parameters)
{

    $final_link = "$parameters";
    $path = strtolower($final_link);
    $file = "$path";

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;       filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "file do not exist";
            redirect('site/file_does_not_exist');
            //$data['main_content'] = 'not_found';
            //$this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
...
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
...
```

From [Internet media types in wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

```
application/pdf: Portable Document Format
```

And also make sure that the file name has the extension ".pdf".